# Tags for wargaming

Tags: feature-request, tags

Currently there is a tag [avalon-hill](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avalon-hill), but no general tag for wargaming.

Also, AH was only one of hundreds, maybe a thousand or more, companies publishing board wargames.

Could somebody add a tag for "wargaming"/"wargames". and perhaps "spi" at least (they were probably bigger than AH).

**Edit**: and also a tag "maps" or "wargame-maps" would be nice.

**More**: needed for [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/43990/wargames-with-multiple-connected-maps).

Comment: The question you provided is an example of a question that is a bad fit for the site because it is looking for a list of games which would be ever growing.

Comment: You have not received any answers because it put on hold for being to broad.

Comment: On meta down votes do signify disagreement with a post

Comment: @TomasBy That question fall under the category of shopping questions. We have a few questions/answers on here about why they are banned, and there is also this Meta.SE discussion about them too: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad

Comment: @TomasBy You are asking for a list of games that fit a certain criteria, on SE those are classified as shopping questions, even if you aren't actually looking to buy something. If you want to know about mechanisms for combining multiple maps in the same game there may be a way to do it here, but asking for a list of games that do it is not the right way. If you want help with writing a question in a way that will stay open feel free to create a new meta question for that.

Answer (score 3):

Tags are created only because a questions needs it, Stack Exchange doesn't provide for a way to create a tag without it being on a question.

If there are specific questions that you think should have those tags and you don't have enough reputation to create tags yourself you can either make another question here on Meta, or comment on the question asking for the tag to be added.